# Use uibutton push to use a function and change a variable value

Tags: matlab, uibutton

I have a problem I do not find a solution to (or maybe I just did not understand it elsewhere on the website...).

Here is my problem: I use a GUI as a uifigure and uibutton inside. When the uibutton is pressed, it calls a function that calculates a curves with input agruments and displays it in the uifigure. The idea of the interface is to press buttons to change variables value and observe the effect on the curve in the display section. So, in the same time than the display, I need to change a variable value in the main script when the button is pushed. My problem is that I cannot find a way to change this variable value at the same time the curve is calculated and displayed.

Here is the script (I simplified it but this gives an idea):

```
tp = 1;

gui_fig = uifigure('Position',[100 100 1300 700]);

p = uipanel(gui_fig,'Position',[10 10 1000 680]);
p.AutoResizeChildren = 'off';

Btntp_min = uibutton(gui_fig, ...
    "Text","-1%", ...
    "fontsize",14,"fontweight",'bold', ...
    "Position",[1060 475 100 30], ...
    "ButtonPushedFcn", @(src,event) Button_tp_min(p,tp));   

function Button_tp_min(ax,tp)
    tp = tp*0.99; % Effect of button        
    bx1 = subplot(2,1,1,'parent',ax);
    plot(bx1,1,tp,'o')
end
```

In this script, the point is to reduce by 1% the value of tp each time the button is pressed. It works the first time, but the reference value keeps being that in the main script. So how is it possible to modify this script so that the new value of tp is considered in the main script ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the value of `tp` you initiate when you define the function is never updated, it is always `1` when the function `Button_tp_min` is fired by the button.

One way to have it work is to reserve a field in the application data of your figure. You can save and retrieve application data with the functions [setappdata](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) and [getappdata](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) respectively.

You first initiate the application data field when you create the figure and save the starting value of `tp`.
Then each time the function `Button_tp_min` runs, it will:

- Retrieve the handle of the top parent figure
- Retrieve the application data field "TP" (and its value) from the figure handle
- ... do what you want/need withthis value of `tp`, then
- Save the modified value of `tp` in the the "TP" application data field.

By adding 4 lines to your code, using these application data, you now have a variable `tp` which is dynamic. Also note that since the variable `tp` is retrieved directly from within the `Button_tp_min` function, it is no longer necessary to provide it as input argument of the function.

```
tp = 1;
gui_fig = uifigure('Position',[100 100 1300 700]);

% save the initial [tp] in application data field named "TP"
setappdata(gui_fig,'TP',tp);

p = uipanel(gui_fig,'Position',[10 10 1000 680]);
p.AutoResizeChildren = 'off';

Btntp_min = uibutton(gui_fig, ...
    "Text","-1%", ...
    "fontsize",14,"fontweight",'bold', ...
    "Position",[1060 475 100 30], ...
    "ButtonPushedFcn", @(src,event) Button_tp_min(p));   

function Button_tp_min(ax)
    gui_fig = ancestor(ax,'figure','toplevel'); % retrieve top figure handle
    tp = getappdata(gui_fig,'TP');              % get the [tp] value
    tp = tp*0.99;                               % Modify [tp] value
    setappdata(gui_fig,'TP',tp);                % save the new [tp] value for next round
    % Display ...
    bx1 = subplot(2,1,1,'parent',ax);
    plot(bx1,1,tp,'o')
end
```

---

Just as a side note, your `tp` value will decrease by 1% of *the previous* value of `tp` (not by 1% of 100 as initialy). To give you an example:

```
tp(1) = 100;
for k=2:10
    tp(k) = tp(k-1)*.99;
end
```

Will give the first 10 values of `tp` as:

```
>> tp =
  100.0000
   99.0000
   98.0100
   97.0299
   96.0596
   95.0990
   94.1480
   93.2065
   92.2745
   91.3517
```

If that is what you wanted everything is fine, otherwise if you wanted a linear decrease (like [100 99 98 97 ...]), consider changing the line `tp = tp*0.99;` into `tp = tp-1;`

Comment: Hi Hoki, 

Thank you for this very complete answer, this is exactly what I needed ! 
That's actually very clever to save the variables in uifigure in an "invisible" (not visible in the GUI) way. I did not know this was possible.

As for your side note, the example was just an example, but thank you anyway for taking time to add it !

Comment: @Thib. No problem happy to help. I recommend you have a look at the MATLAB documentation page: [Maintain or Transition figure-Based Apps](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/develop-apps-using-the-figure-function.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav), and particularly the functions described in the section `"App Data and Preferences"`. There will be lots of usefull tips on how to pass variables around in a gui based app.